# Envers with Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate-envers

I am using Envers for auditing some of my DB Tables. 
Auditing is woking fine, I can see the data in the DB in the corresponding tables with my custom prefix etc.
I can't query any data becouse I am getting always the following QueryException:

could not resolve property: originalId of: NaturalPerson [select e__, r__ from NaturalPerson  e__, ExtendedRevisionEntity r__ where e__.originalId.RevisionID.id = r__.id order by e__.originalId.RevisionID.id asc]

This is the query code:

```
AuditReaderFactory.Get(session).CreateQuery().ForHistoryOf<NaturalPerson, ExtendedRevisionEntity>().Results();
```

Mappings for NaturalPerson

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="Domain" namespace="Domain" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <joined-subclass name="NaturalPerson"  schema="MySchema" table="NaturalPersons">
    <key column="PersonID" />
    <property name="Name" type="AnsiString"/>
  </joined-subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Envers config using fluent:

```
configuration.SetEnversProperty(ConfigurationKey.AuditTableSuffix, " ");
configuration.SetEnversProperty(ConfigurationKey.DefaultSchema, "aud"); 
configuration.SetEnversProperty(ConfigurationKey.StoreDataAtDelete, true);
configuration.SetEnversProperty(ConfigurationKey.RevisionFieldName, "RevisionID");
configuration.SetEnversProperty(ConfigurationKey.RevisionTypeFieldName, "RevisionTypeID");
enversConf.Audit<NaturalPerson>();
```

Comment: Mappings and envers configuration for NaturalPerson please.

Comment: I added that information in the answer

Comment: The "from NaturalPerson" part look a bit suspicious. Can you look at the generated sql and verify that is actually trying to read from the audit table? Setting AuditTableSuffix to blank/spaces _might_ be the problem.

Comment: You are correct, the space in the suffix IS the problem, it is terribly annoying that it works for writing but you can't query, I think it could be a bug in the envers query API

Comment: Do you know if there is any way of taking envers suffix away? I have tried using string.Empty but Nhibernate wont let me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments above, the problem is the "only spaces" in the AuditTableSuffix.

The audited entity name in code is
*audittableprefix + "original entity name" + audittablesuffix*

When querying, the "empty space" means nothing ("`select a from  b a`" becomes "`select a from b a`") and wrong data will be read.

Please add a JIRA issue about it here
https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NHE
preferably with a small, isolated failing test.